# Lambda em Java 8 lançando Exception

Tags: java, exceção, expressões-lambda

Tenho o seguinte problema.

Preciso realizar um processo de atualização de usuário e seu grupo, e para realizar a alteração realizo a busca do usuário, validando se o mesmo existe e logo após, busco o grupo verificando se ele existe, caso algum erro aconteça eu subo uma nova `Exception` informando.

Porém, quando utilizo o `orElseThrow` do grupo dentro de um lambda tenho o retorno do seguinte erro pela IDE:

> Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception

Segue código abaixo:

```
    public UserDTO updateUser(UserDTO dto) throws Exception {
    if (dto.getId() == null) {
        throw new Exception("Usuario não informado corretamente para atualização.");
    }

    // buscando dados de usuario
    final Optional<UserEntity> user = repository.findById(dto.getId());
    user.ifPresent(u -> {
        u.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
        u.setStatus(dto.isStatus());

        // buscando referencia de grupo
        final Optional<GroupEntity> group = groupService.getGroup(dto.getGroupId());

        // grupo nao encontrado
        group.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Grupo não encontrado"));

        // grupo encontrado
        group.ifPresent(g -> {
            u.setGroupEntity(g);
        });

        repository.save(u);
    });

    // usuario nao encontrado
    user.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Usuario não encontrado"));

    return dto;
}
```

Comment: Precisa ver a definição  do `ifPresent`. Eu acho que é um `Consumer`, que não tem em sua definição o lançamento de exceção

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas e exceções verificadas não formam uma mistura boa. Mas antes disso, `throws Exception` e `throw new Exception` são más práticas de programação.

Você deveria lançar e tratar exceções específicas e não exceções genéricas.

Além disso, você pode usar a exceção para se livrar tanto do `null` quanto do `Optional`. Observe que [o `orElseThrow(...)` retorna o objeto encapsulado dentro do `Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)).

Tente fazer assim:

```
public static class NotFoundException extends Exception {
    public NotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public UserDTO updateUser(UserDTO dto) throws NotFoundException {
    if (dto.getId() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Usuário não informado corretamente para atualização.");
    }

    // Busca referência de usuário. Lança exceção se não encontrado.
    final UserEntity u = repository
            .findById(dto.getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Usuário não encontrado"));

    // Busca referência de grupo. Lança exceção se não encontrado.
    final GroupEntity g = groupService
            .getGroup(dto.getGroupId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Grupo não encontrado"));

    u.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
    u.setStatus(dto.isStatus());
    u.setGroupEntity(g);
    repository.save(u);

    return dto;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou seguir a instrução sobre a pratica de programação. Novamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: @AbraãoBorgesNeves De nada. Foi um prazer ajudar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

O problema está aqui:

```
//...
user.ifPresent(u -> {
    //...
    group.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Grupo não encontrado"));
    //...
});
//...
```

Ao utilizar uma lambda nesse caso, você está passando para o método `ifPresent` um `Consumer` cuja implementação do método `accept` é o código entre as chaves. Como na assinatura desse método não está definido que ele pode lançar uma *checked exception*, o compilador te informa do erro. Para corrigi-lo, você deve tratar a *checked exception* dentro da lambda (o que não é viável no seu caso, já que você quer lançar a exceção para indicar um problema).

Esse erro não ocorre com *unchecked exceptions*, já que um método que as lança, não precisa especificá-la em sua assinatura. Então elas se tornam boas candidatas para solucionar o seu problema.

Você poderia criar uma exceção que estenda da `RuntimeException` para sinalizar o erro de uma entidade não encontrada:

```
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException { 
    public EntityNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

E lançar a exceção dessa forma:

```
//...
user.ifPresent(u -> {
    //...
    group.orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Grupo não encontrado"));
    //...
});
//...
```

Um exemplo funcional do lançamento de *unchecked exceptions* dentro de uma expressão lambda pode ser testado [aqui](https://ideone.com/HFLNBf).